# Jquery Ajax call doesn't work fine in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading some data lively from the database and each row have some links that do some things over that.

They work flawlessly except for the last one I've implemented which seems not to be working on IE

```
$('.lockFile').click(function(){
var url = "functions/lock_call.php";
var unlock = 'assets/lock-unlock.png';
var lock = 'assets/lock.png';
var action = 'unlock';
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var image = $(this).children(0);
if (image.attr('src') == unlock)
    action = 'lock';
var data = 'id='+id+'&action='+action;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert (action);
        if (action == 'lock')
            image.attr('src', lock);
        else
            image.attr('src', unlock);
    }
});
return false;
```

});

What could be wrong?

The alert is performer on "success" but nothing is made. That is, the script doesn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 8 has some amazing variables reserved, try this one

```
$('.lockFile').click(function(){
                            var Aurl = "functions/lock_call.php";
                            var AunAlock = 'assets/lock-unlock.png';
                            var Alock = 'assets/lock.png';
                            var Aaction = 'AunAlock';
                            var Aid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                            var Aimage = $(this).children(0);
                            if (image.attr('src') == AunAlock)
                                Aaction = 'Alock';
                            var data = 'id='+Aid+'&action='+Aaction;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: Aurl,
                                data: data,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(){
                                    alert (Aaction);
                                    if (Aaction == 'lock')
                                        Aimage.attr('src', Alock);
                                    else
                                        Aimage.attr('src', AunAlock);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
```

Comment: I honestly think the *values* can be left intact. Now the data sent is different.

Comment: This worked but now I need to perform 2 clicks to get this work in IE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to declare data in JSON format 
var data = {'id':id, 'action': action}